# How can i make a column that can take a list of elements?

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have a table with 3 columns(id,city and country) and I'm trying to add one more(address) that can take multiple values.Here is an example of how a row looks like : Id:1, city:Paris, country:France and i need something like that Id:1, city:Paris, country:France, address:Charonne,Invalides. How i can do this ?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another table:

```
CREATE TABLE location(
  id      NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT location__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  city    VARCHAR2(100),
  country VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE location_addresses(
  id          NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT location_addr__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  location_id NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT location_addr__li__fk FOREIGN KEY
                             REFERENCES location( id ),
  address     VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Or, use a nested table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/

CREATE TABLE location(
  id      NUMBER(10,0) CONSTRAINT location__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  city    VARCHAR2(100),
  country VARCHAR2(100),
  address StringList
) NESTED TABLE address STORE AS location_addresses;
```

(*Note: the first option allows you to apply constraints to the table - i.e. you could add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `location_id` and `address` to prevent duplicates or a `NOT NULL` constraint on `address` - however, you cannot add constraints as easily to a nested table.*)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing it in same table, create another `Address` table.

The structure of table can be

```
ID ADDRESS

1 Charonne
1 Invalides
```

This will help in normalizing the table. You can access the address of any user by using join between both the tables.